# Get UI element at the touch co-ordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, coordinates

I'm sure I've read that there is a way of getting co-ordinates on TouchDown in a WPF app and finding out what UI elements are 'underneath' this touch. Can anyone help?

Comment: why do you want to know the UI elements are 'underneath' this touch ? do you need to exclude it from manipulation? 
when do you need it ? at manipulation delta ?

Comment: I do, I've been trying to figure out how to exclude my buttons from a Page-swipe manipulation. *sigh* See here: http://goo.gl/pCdVSr

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a [hit test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) against the visual tree.

Here is an example with mouse click (but touch is more or less the same thing in this respect):

```
// Respond to the left mouse button down event by initiating the hit test.
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the coordinate of the mouse position.
    Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

    // Perform the hit test against a given portion of the visual object tree.
    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(myCanvas, pt);

    if (result != null)
    {
        // Perform action on hit visual object.
    } 
}
```

Other overload of [HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx) can give you multiple hit visuals.

Comment: What's myCanvas in this example?

Comment: What if all I want to do is filter out content from Manipulation? http://goo.gl/pCdVSr

Answer (score 0):

Let your UI elements extend UIElement class like this:

```
class MyUIElement : UIElement
    {
        protected override void OnManipulationStarting(System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnManipulationStarting(e);
            UIElement involvedUIElement = e.Source as UIElement;

            // to cancel the touch manipulaiton:
            e.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

involvedUIElement should hold the UI elements that raised the touch event, if you need to cancel the manipulation for specific elements you just need to call `e.Cancel();`

I hope this will help!